# Java finalize : How can I free non-GC resource even if there's mistake

Tags: java, .net

As I know, there's no guarantee that `Object.finalize()` is called always. but If there an important non-GC resource, and user didn't call `close()` accidentally, How can I free the resource?

PS. Does `Object.Finalize()` in .NET have the same problem? If so, how can I solve this problem in that case?

Comment: Question is about java or .net? or both?

Comment: You can't free the resource---as simple as that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik In .Net you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `try-finally` or better `try-with-resources`

```
try(Resource res = /*aquire resource*/){
//do stuff
}catch(Exception e //or watever){
//handle exceptions
}
```

and how to do it before Java7 :

```
Resource res = null;
try{
res = //aquire resource
    //do stuff 
}catch(Exception e /*or whatever*/){
 //handle exceptions
}finally{
    if(null != res){
        res.close();
    }
}
```

In .Net you should use

```
using (Resource resource = /*aquire resource*/)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

The simple answer is that `YOU CANNOT`. Such behavior is a `BUG` and you should locate it and fix it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. user didn't close the resources

Comment: If he uses try-finally/try-with-resources there won't have that problem.

Comment: OP asks how to free-up the resource, which is not closed at all in Java and .NET

Comment: Thanks! So, there's no way to catch and prevent programmer's mistake;;  By the way, catch(Exception e //or watever){ <- Is this your mistype? ) and { are commented out and I think watever should be whatever asdfasdf

Comment: sorry, the `}` should not be commented. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

.Net have the same problem, `Finalize` method is not reliable. So in .Net 2.0 to address this problem [Safe Handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh21e17c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are introduced, which provides a reliable way to release the unmanaged resource.

All you have to do is inherit your class from `SafeHandle` or `CriticalHandle`. These both indeed derives from `CritialFinializationObject` which turns to be the key for reliablity.

Read more about safehandles [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/16/396900.aspx).

P.S:This is only partial answer, am a .Net guy so apologizes for no java part of answer.

Comment: I've just read about safe handles from your link and they seem to address issues which don't even exist in Java, while still being as weak a mechanism as Java finalizers.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Am not sure about which issues you think doesn't even exist in java?

Comment: Accessing a resource over a handle which has already been invalidated, and then reused for another resource. `SafeHandle` is about preventing the usage of a *freed* resource handle as if it was still taken.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik `SafeHandle` is not only about preventing the usage of a freed resource handle as if it was still taken. Its main goal is to release the resource which was not cleaned up properly in time.

Comment: Are there any timeliness guarantees for it? As in, "the resource is guaranteed to be freed within 10 ms of its handle becoming unreachable"? If not, then it's in the same class of reliability as Java's finalizers.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik No timely guarantee; but it is the part of garbage collection. you can't expect finalizers to be called for sure, but you can expect safe handle's `Finalize` will be called for sure **before the object's memory is reclaimed**

Comment: Yes, that's what I have in mind: Java doesn't need SafeHandles for that. However the inadequacy of the finalization mechanism is the premise of this question and OP is asking how to improve on it.

Comment: Um, The msdn says "The finalizer for any types deriving from CriticalFinalizerObject is given the opportunity to execute and will not be aborted, assuming the finalizer correctly follows the rules for a constrained execution region (CER).". Must I study how to write CER code to use this solution? T.T

Comment: Here are the guidelines to write [CER code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`finalize` has the same problem in .NET (i.e. if the object is never garbage collected, then finalize will never be called)

In Java, the best practice to guarantee cleanup is:

```
final Resource resource = getResource();
try {
    // Do stuff
    ...
} finally {
    resource.dispose();
}
```

In .NET, the best practice to guarantee cleanup is:

```
using (Resource resource = GetResource())
{
    // Do stuff
    ...
}
```

Comment: This also doesn't answers the question

Comment: doesn't answer it , because there is no answer to this question! It's the programmer's responsibility to take care of the resources, and when the program has a memory leak it's again the programmers responsibility to find it and fix it. If he doesn't use the mechanisms for resource management provided in the language it.s again his problem. He should find those pieces of code and fix them accordingly!!!

Comment: @SvetlinZarev **Why no answer?** there is an answer, atleast for .net. refer my answer for details!

Comment: Well, I'm not much into .Net so I cannot comment on your answer, but either way it does not work for java. And this is more like a workaround for the `real` problem, rather than a fix. Also it does not work for third party code, which may leak resources internally. So strictly speaking it doesn't answer the question :)