# Garbage Collector : finalize isn't always called?

Tags: garbage-collection, boehm-gc

My question is related to [Java finalize : How can I free non-GC resource even if there's mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214948/java-finalize-how-can-i-free-non-gc-resource-even-if-theres-mistake) .

1. The `finalize` is NOT always called in most Garbage Collectors? If so, Why not? and Is there any GC that guarantee call `finalize` before program is *normally* exit?
2. I use boehm-gc in some project. Does boehm-gc guarantee call `finalize` before program is normally exit? If not, Is there any way to call `finalize` when program is normally exit? (so to speak, call `GC_gcollect` before `main` returns.)